# Equation of a tangent when the slope of tangent is in terms of variables x and y

Tags: conic-sections

Where am I getting wrong here?

In equations with higher power of variables, x and y, to find their tangent, on differentiating we get the slope in terms of the variables itself.

Now if we take one such restrains from conic sections, we know that all their tangents are linear in power. But then I get this:

y=(x/y)x +c

I get stuck in this step every time
What should be done so as to find the c and return the equation back to linear ?

Comment: You need to plug in the values of $(x,y)$ from the point of tangent in $x/y$ to get slope of tangent at a given point on the conic.

Comment: The right equation is: $y=(x_0/y_0)x +c$.

Comment: Thank you so much !